# Communicating between frames in Delphi

Tags: delphi, frames

I just started using Frames in Delphi.

That Frames are in FrameBar1 and they both are visible. Just for testing, first one contains one Button and second Frame contains one Edit.

I want to change text in Edit with click on Button (which are controls on two different frames).

How to ***communicate*** between frames?

Comment: Frames are intended to be self-contained. It's their parent which is meant to handle such interaction. Not that it's not possible, but not by design. Keep in mind, if you're only going to be using a frame in one place, it makes no sense. Frames are meant to re-use the same set of controls numerous times.

Comment: @JerryDodge frames have many benefits besides re-use. Frames can contain complex code that you may not want to include in a parent form (separation), great for swapping etc..

Comment: @JohnEasley True, but I always use embedded forms for that. Much more flexible. For example, Frames don't have an OnCreate/OnDestroy event.

Comment: Long story short, don't rely on the Delphi IDE to provide all your UI needs. The best applications have a lot of intelligent code manually written for the UI. The components built-in to Delphi are considered a "starting point" for me. More or less a prototype. Production comes from raw dynamic code which does what's needed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same way you would if the controls were in the same Form.  Just prefix the Edit control with the Frame object that owns it, eg:

```
uses
  Frame1Unit, Frame2Unit;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame1 := TFrame1.Create(Self);
  Frame1.Parent := ...;
  ...
  Frame2 := TFrame2.Create(Self);
  Frame2.Parent := ...;
  ...
end;
```

```
uses
  Frame2Unit;

procedure TFrame1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame2.Edit1.Text := '...';
end;
```

A better design would be to encapsulate the logic so Frame1 and Frame2 do not know about each other. Have Frame1 expose an event that it fires when the button is clicked, and then the parent Form can assign a handler to that event and assign the text on the Frame2, eg:

```
uses
  Frame1Unit, Frame2Unit;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Frame1 := TFrame1.Create(Self);
  Frame1.Parent := ...;
  Frame1.OnNewText := Frame1Text;
  ...
  Frame2 := TFrame2.Create(Self);
  Frame2.Parent := ...;
  ...
end;

procedure TForm1.Frame1Text(Sender: TObject; const NewText: string);
begin
  Frame2.EditText := NewText;
end;
```

```
type
  TFrame1TextEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; const NewText; string) of object;

  TFrame1 = class(TFrame)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  public
    OnNewText: TFrame1TextEvent;
  end;

procedure TFrame1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(OnNewText) then
    OnNewText(Self, '...');
end;
```

```
type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    function GetEditText: string;
    procedure SetEditText(const Value: string);
  public
    property EditText: string read GetEditText write SetEditText;
  end;

function TFrame2.GetEditText: string;
begin
  Result := Edit1.Text;
end;

procedure TFrame2.SetEditText(const Value: string);
begin
  Edit1.Text := Value;
end;
```